# Warning: require_once(../DAO/ConexionLB.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\TFC\LaBiblioteca\DAO\Busquedas.php

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo pruebas para ver la conexión con la BBDD y al ejecutar el archivo PruebasPhp.php me da este error de que no encuentra el archivo del requiere_once. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] Pero me salta el siguiente error:(Warning: require_once(../DAO/ConexionLB.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\TFC\LaBiblioteca\DAO\Busquedas.php on line 2

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '../DAO/ConexionLB.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\TFC\LaBiblioteca\DAO\Busquedas.php:2 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\TFC\LaBiblioteca\PruebasPhp.php(4): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\TFC\LaBiblioteca\DAO\Busquedas.php on line 2) [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Con la ruta: ./LaBiblioteca/DAO/ y apuntando al archivo de conexión o al archivo del Dao también me sale el mismo error. Agradecería mucho la ayuda.

Comment: Hola. Considera poner el código como texto. Por otra parte, no uses nunca esta parte en tus rutas: **`C:\xampp\htdocs`**, eso es un entorno local, y ese código fallará cuando lo pases a un servidor remoto. Puedes empezar a referir las rutas desde la carpeta que contiene los archivos, en este caso `TFC`. Para evitar problemas de este tipo, te recomendaría que definas todas tus rutas en un archivo, que pondrías en el directorio principal, luego incluyes ese archivo y usas las constantes de las rutas para incluir los archivos.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.